# Can I read the model file back from model.ExportToFile('test.pd.txt') in Or-Tools CP-SAT and solve it again for debug purpose

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I have a file generated from model.ExportToFile('test.pd.txt') in ortools CP-SAT. can I read the txt file back and solve it again for debug purpose?

we can do this in other solvers like, cplex, gurobi. But i do know how to do it in OR-Tools CP-SAT.

read the model txt file directly and then solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary sat_runner can load and run saved models.

```
sat_runner --input proto_file --params params_in_text_format
```

The source is in `ortools/sat/sat_runner.cc`

See also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/jg-LYSWAgZA/m/H34lueYWAgAJ?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i can run it now. 
BTW, is it possible for us to do it in python with some pre defined method? If not, will it be in roadmap.

Comment: the info in the link does help. Thanks